# All apache requests to Symfony Routing Component

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I started to make a website and i want to use only decoupled components (installed through composer) that i will need in my project. 
The first component i want to use is symfony/routing component. 
So i made a php file (the front controller) and i want all user requests to be redirected to this front controller. What best practices to do that?

I tried it to do with the .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontController.php [L]
```

So any request will be redirected to the front controller. 
But is it secure and well written?
Maybe there is some best practices for cases like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial will be perfect for your needs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html

Especially the routing part:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/routing.html

Regarding your specific question, you may want to add a few more rules before, e.g. if a file exists do not redirect but just serve the file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```

The .htaccess included in Symfony Standard Edition is a good example.